# Hover em um elemento e alterando a cor de um outro elemento

Tags: css, css-hover

Gostaria que ao passar o mouse sobre o elemento verde o rosa alterasse para a cor azul.

```css
#primeiro{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
   float: left; 
}
#segundo{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
  margin: auto; 
}
#segundo:hover #efeito{
  background: blue;
}
#efeito{
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background: pink;
  float: left; 
}
```

```html
<div id="primeiro"><div id="segundo"></div></div>

<div id="efeito"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Explicando o porque de não esta funcionando**

Da forma que você fez:

```
#segundo:hover #efeito{
  background: blue;
}
```

Só funcionaria se a div "efeito" estivesse dentro da div "segundo".

**Solução com javascript**

Você pode fazer este efeito utilizando javascript:

```
var segundo = document.getElementById("segundo");
var efeito = document.getElementById("efeito");

segundo.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
segundo.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut);

function mouseOver() {
    efeito.style.background = "blue";
}

function mouseOut() {
    efeito.style.background = "pink";
}
```

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/hkLxpk7e/

**Recurso disponível do css**

Encontrei apenas uma forma de fazer utilizando apenas css, mas esta forma a div tem que esta na mesma "altura" que a outra, como a div "segunda" esta dentro da div "primeira" já não vai funcionar, funcionaria se o hover estivesse na div "primeira" já que a div "efeito" vem depois dela.

Uma div seguida da outra:

```
#a:hover + #b {
    background: #ccc
}

<div id="a">Div A</div>
<div id="b">Div B</div>
```

Com uma div seguida da outra, mas com outras no meio.

```
#a:hover ~ #b {
    background: #ccc
}

<div id="a">Div A</div>
<div>random other elements</div>
<div>random other elements</div>
<div>random other elements</div>
<div id="b">Div B</div>
```

Exemplo utilizando a div "primeira": https://jsfiddle.net/hkLxpk7e/1/

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling)

**Solução utilizando apenas o css**

Você pode alterar a estrutura do html também, desta forma:

```
<div id="primeiro">
  <div id="segundo"></div>
  <div id="efeito">sd</div>
</div>
```

Assim é possível utilizar somente css para criar o seu efeito, porem tornasse necessário manipular a div "efeito" para ficar no canto direito superior, desta forma:

```
#primeiro{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
   float: left; 
}
#segundo{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
  margin: auto; 
}
#efeito{
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background: pink;
  float: left; 
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:300px;
  top:8px;
}
#segundo:hover ~ #efeito {
    background: blue
}
```

Resultado: https://jsfiddle.net/hkLxpk7e/2/